# Past year sales value flag in tableau

Tags: tableau-api, visualization

I have a graph where I have sales value  for Jan, Feb, Mar state wise. I want to mark a flag in a column, if sales exceeds previous month for March month say.

```
                    Sales     Sales   Sales
  City1 Person 1     12        29     10
        Person 2     14        15     19
        Person 3     23        24     11
  
  City2 Person 4     22        28     30
        Person 5     14        15     10
        Person 6     23        24     2
  
                      Jan      Feb     Mar and so on
```

So basically expected output would be:

```
                    Sales     Sales   Sales   Flag
  City1 Person 1     12        29     10       Down arrow
        Person 2     14        15     19       Up arrow
        Person 3     23        24     11       Down Arrow
  
  City2 Person 4     22        28     30       Up arrow 
        Person 5     14        15     10       Down arrow
        Person 6     23        24     2        Down arrow
  
                      Jan      Feb     Mar and so on
```

Can anyone tell how to do this in a graph visualisation?

The values of sales are sum (Sales) for Jan , Feb and Mar respectively for Cities corresponding to each person

Comment: You want a flag for every month indicating whether it's higher than the previous month? If that's the case you could do this with colour in a heat map, one colour for up vs last month, another colour for down..

Comment: There's a couple different ways. Check out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nuW7VkDNL4s or https://community.tableau.com/s/question/0D54T00000C69xGSAR/kpi-indicators-with-updown-arrows

Comment: How to do that in the heatmap too